# Are variables on stack collected by garbage collector?

Tags: variables, go, compiler-construction, garbage-collection

I would like to understand how the stack variables are deallocated. Is it garbage collected as variables located on heap, or like C languages which after leaving the variable scope it will be deallocated internally ?

Comment: Yees, but that's not i meant when i talked about C. Now i rewrote the question for better comprehension. Thank you for that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable allocated on the stack will be removed once the function allocating that variable returns because the stack pointer will be restored to its state before the function call. There is no GC involvement there.

In Go, if the stack variable is a pointer to an object on the heap, then once the function returns, the pointer will be removed, and then the GC can remove the object it was pointing to provided no other references exist.

Comment: The second paragraph only applies to languages that admit GC (which does not include C).

Comment: True, however, the way I read the question, "...such as C" applies to the "after leaving..." part and not "..garbage collected.." part of the sentence.

Comment: Indeed I don't think the answer is wrong, just slightly unclear on that point.

Comment: What about a function returning a pointer that references a function value? This value will not be reclaimed off the stack long as the caller keeps the reference.

Comment: @colminator, Speaking for Go: It does escape analysis. Any variable whose address escapes the function will not be allocated on the stack, it will be allocated in heap.

Comment: Thank you @BurakSerdar that was what i ask for. Sorry for the lack of clarity of the question, now i rewrote the question.